# how big should site CSS files be?

Tags: css, html, sass, compass-sass, codekit

I am aware of CSS and HTML5 and a little bit of jQuery.

I am testing around with SASS and Compass. Alongside tools such as Sublime Text 2 and Codekit.

However my CSS files (minified) are totaling 106KB. I have included the Foundation 3 framework, and my own Typekit fonts. The pre-compiled size is around 35kb..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your CSS depends on your site requirements. As long as it is lean and efficient in what it does you are doing it correctly, there can not possibly be a set size for CSS/HTML or JS files!

There is [this good site speed tool by Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights) which will help you improve speed as I am guessing that is the aim?